# VBA , Using offset

Tags: vba, excel

I am having 4 sht, sht1, sht2, sht3 and sht4.

I am copying the columns E and F from sht 1 to sht3. and then i look into  the corresponding values in sht 2, and paste them in sht3.

I then lookinto in my sht3, if the column "G" has "NO"; then i copy the corresponding rows to sht4.

till, this i have completed coding.

I wanted to look into the column E in sht4, and paste the corresponding ID from sht1. Could someone tell, how i could do it ?

EDIT.

In sht3, i have the rows filled only when there is Id in column F.

In few cases, i dont have column F,means there is no ID.

so, i copy them to sht4. Now i have in sht4, column E Filled. I want to look into the relevant Information of those ID in sht1. I want the Information from each and every column in sht1, except E .

I know we can use Offset, but how do I use it in this case,
I have tried the following code

```
Sub nlookup()
Dim i As Long
Dim totalrows As Long
Dim rng As Range
Sheets("sht1").Select
totalrows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Sheets("sht4").Select
For i = 5 To totalrows
Set rng = Sheets("sht2").UsedRange.Find(Cells(i, 5).Value)
'If it is found put its value on the destination sheet
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
Cells(i, 6).Value = rng.Value
Cells(i, 1).Value = rng.Offset(0, 0).Value
Cells(i, 2).Value = rng.Offset(0, 14).Value
Cells(i, 3).Value = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
Cells(i, 4).Value = rng.Offset(0, 2).Value
Cells(i, 12).Value = rng.Offset(0, 8).Value
Cells(i, 13).Value = rng.Offset(0, 9).Value
End If
Next
End Sub
```

> Set rng = Sheets("sht2").UsedRange.Find(Cells(i, 5).Value), there is no Need of looking into this line, i beleive.

[image: Image of sht4. which is extracted from sht3.]
[image: Image of sht1]

Comment: @pnuts, I will make sure, hereafter i look into the tags carefully before i do.

Comment: How do you know where the ID is in sht1 in comparison to sht4?

Comment: the id in sht4, is in column E and the id in sht 1 is in column N

Comment: I will do it shortly. Once i am finished with this Task.

Comment: I am unable to understand your question. You are saying `i look into the corresponding values in sht 2, and paste them in sht3` and you have done that. So now  `look into the column E in sht4, and paste the corresponding ID from sht1` should also be doable. Though to understand your problem completely, sample data and desired output will be helpful.

Comment: @Mrig, Is it possible, i could edit the question, right now the idea is different.

Comment: Will be better if you can edit the question.

Comment: Ya, i will do it now. But it will be different from this  ? is that ok ?

Comment: You can write **EDIT** and add whatever you want to under it, leaving the already existing question as it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148405/discussion-between-mikz-and-mrig).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code will consider the following as discussed in chat:

1. Data should be copied from `sht1` to `sht4` on Id's in both sheets
2. Id's are in `Column L` and `Column E` for `sht1` and `sht4` respectively
3. Columns to be copy from `sht1` to `sht4` as `A->A`, `B->C`,`C->D`,`I->L`,`J->M`,`O->B`
4. Data in `sht1` and `sht4` starts from `Row 5` and `Row 2` respectively

   ```
   Sub Demo()
       Dim srcLastRow As Long, destLastRow As Long
       Dim srcWS As Worksheet, destWS As Worksheet
       Dim i As Long, j As Long

       Application.ScreenUpdating = False

       Set srcWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sht1")
       Set destWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sht4")
       srcLastRow = srcWS.Cells(srcWS.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
       destLastRow = destWS.Cells(destWS.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

       For i = 2 To destLastRow
           For j = 5 To srcLastRow
               If destWS.Cells(i, "E").Value = srcWS.Cells(j, "L").Value Then
                   destWS.Cells(i, "A") = srcWS.Cells(j, "A")
                   destWS.Cells(i, "B") = srcWS.Cells(j, "O")
                   destWS.Cells(i, "C") = srcWS.Cells(j, "B")
                   destWS.Cells(i, "D") = srcWS.Cells(j, "C")
                   destWS.Cells(i, "L") = srcWS.Cells(j, "I")
                   destWS.Cells(i, "M") = srcWS.Cells(j, "J")
               End If
           Next j
       Next i

       Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `Cells(i, 4).Value = rng.Cells(i, 6).Value` ? 
Also get rid of the`.Select`

```
Sub nlookup()
dim sht as Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim totalrows As Long
Dim rng As Range

totalrows = Sheets("sht1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set sht = Worksheets("sht4")

For i = 5 To totalrows
Set rng = Sheets("sht2").UsedRange.Find(sht.Cells(i, 5).Value)
'If it is found put its value on the destination sheet
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
sht.Cells(i, 6).Value = rng.Value
sht.Cells(i, 1).Value = rng.Cells(i, 1).Value
sht.Cells(i, 2).Value = rng.Cells(i, 16).Value
sht.Cells(i, 3).Value = rng.Cells(i, 4).Value
sht.Cells(i, 4).Value = rng.Cells(i, 6).Value
sht.Cells(i, 12).Value = rng.Cells(i, 20).Value
sht.Cells(i, 13).Value = rng.Cells(i, 22).Value
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: but how does this, return my value from sheet1 ?

Comment: also, i dont want to look into sht2 here. all i have to do now, is .. consider column E of sheet4, and take the matching data of column a , b, c , d and so on from sht1 and paste them in sht4.